# [ApacheBeam RedisIO]: how to retrieve with PFCOUNT the count of all the unique queries

Tags: redis, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm creating a pipeline that needs to read data from Redis. All the elements were added using PFADD (HyperLogLog) data structure.

That said, it seems that apache beam does not support PFCOUNT command.

Does anyone know how to go over this problem?

I looked at the code and I feel like it's a gap of implementation where an initial solution would be creating a function like

```
 public Response<Long> readUsingPFCOUNTCommand(String key) {
   

   return pipeline.pfcount(key, value);

   
  }
```

Comment: Please create a Jira feature request if you think this is a missing feature that should be added to Beam RedisIO - https://beam.apache.org/community/contact-us/

Comment: Thanks for the comment @chamikara, the ticket was created: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-13326